# IllegalStateException on ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity that uses a viewpager. Since the data might mot be available from the web, I show a progress bar. When I have the data, I reset the activity by injecting the info into a bundle, then calling onCreate(bundle). This has worked before, but I get the following when using the technique in the viewpager activity.

```
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachActivity(FragmentManager.java:1829)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:185)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.skinanalytics.skinuploader.ui.ActivityDashboard.onCreate(ActivityDashboard.java:77)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.skinanalytics.skinuploader.ui.ActivityDashboard$3.onSuccess(ActivityDashboard.java:203)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleSuccessMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:160)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:173)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$1.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:85)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-27 15:44:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i think part of the stack trace is missing

Comment: i don't think you are supposed to call onCreate. may be you just need to show/hide view

Comment: When you make the view visible/invisible, the space it takes up is still kept for it, right?

Comment: thanks! Not the answer to my question, but a huge help :).

Comment: Can you please provide your code?